# How do I implement long click event in the extended ListFragment class?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have successfully achieved event handling for ListFragment by the use of Common Listener which will be used by several Fragments in a activity. I was managed to implement onListItemClick in the ListFragment. But I am struggling to get the long click/press event on the same ListFragment done by the use of common listener.

What will be a most appropriate approach without deviate from the common listener approach???

My ListFragment code is as bellow

```
public class UnSettled_itemsFragment extends ListFragment {

    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    private DB db;
    private Checque currentchqobj;
    private String currentchqnumber;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener selectListener;   // Reference to Common FragmentListener

    public UnSettled_itemsFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        currentchqnumber = bundle.getString("message");
        currentchqobj=Checques.getChecqueByChecquekNo(currentchqnumber);

        Invoice[] invoice=OSInvoices.getInvoices();   // Get the OSInvoice

        // Inflate the ListView
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_unsettled_invoice_list, container, false);

        final OSInvoiceAdapter adapter = new OSInvoiceAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.invoice_list_single, invoice);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }



    @Override
    // SingleClick Listner
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // Create the Invoice reference at the selected Item
        final Invoice invoice = (Invoice) l.getItemAtPosition(position);

        // Pass the Cursor and the TAG to universal listener
        selectListener.onListFragmentInteraction("TAG_UN_INV_SINGLE", invoice);
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (activity instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            selectListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement SelectionFragmentListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDetach();
        selectListener = null;
    }
```

The Common Listener code is as bellow

```
package utill;

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener<T> {
    void onListFragmentInteraction(String tag, T data);
}
```

The Code of the Activity which is Dynamically Creating the Fragments are as bellow

```
public class AddChecqueV2 extends Activity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener<Object> {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /*

    Some Code

    */
    // Display UnSettled Invoice List Fragment
                Bundle bundle_Un = new Bundle();
                String myMessage_Un = current_cheque_number;
                bundle.putString("message", myMessage_Un );
                UnSettled_itemsFragment fragobj_Un = new UnSettled_itemsFragment();
                fragobj_Un.setArguments(bundle_Un);

                FragmentTransaction transaction_Un = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                transaction_Un.replace(R.id.settlement_Unsettled_fragment_container, fragobj_Un);
                transaction_Un.commit();

    }

    // Implement the Universal Fragment Listener
        // This will handle all the On xxx events in the Fragment
        @Override
        public void onListFragmentInteraction(String tag, Object data) {

            DB heading_db=new DB(AddChecqueV2.this);
            Cursor selectedInvCursor;
            Invoice selectedInvoiceListItem;
            double billBalance = 0;
            final String chequeNo = "CH/"+ String.format("%06d", heading_db.getChequeNo())+heading_db.getRefName();

            //Implement the Listener action for the Unsettled Invoices Single Click Actions
            if(tag.equals("TAG_UN_INV_SINGLE")){
                //################ UNSETTLED INVOICE SELECTION CODE <<<< START >>>> ################## 
                selectedInvoiceListItem = (Invoice) data;
                double selectedInvBalance;
                String selectedInvoice = selectedInvoiceListItem.getInvoiceNo();  
                // Check if the Invoice is already selected
                if(Invoices.isInvoiceExist(selectedInvoice)){
                    selectedInvBalance = selectedInvoiceListItem.getBalance();
                }
                else{
                    selectedInvBalance = selectedInvoiceListItem.getBalance();
                }
      }

//Implement the Listener action for the Unsettled Invoices Long Click Actions
        if(tag.equals("TAG_UN_INV_LONG")){

        // *****
        // This is the place my Long Click Code Goes


}

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListFragment doesn't provide an override convenience method for handling an item's long click. You can set one yourself on the underlying `ListView` though:

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: My actual issue is to capture the onListFragmentItemLongClick event in the fragment. In my fragment class why can't I override the  onListFragmentItemLongClick event? When I am trying to override using               @Override
 public void onListFragmentItemLongClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
 
  super.onListFragmentItemLongClick(l, v, position, id);

 }   it gives the error The method onListFragmentItemLongClick(ListView, View, int, long) of type UnSettled_itemsFragment must override or implement a supertype method. What super method I should override in ListFragment?

Comment: Oh. Your question was unclear that was what your issue was. I updated my answer.

Comment: See updated updated answer. Also, I recommend you review the ListView documentation and familiarize yourself with the methods available to you.

Comment: @ dominicoder. I need to get the selected item position from the listview. How can I get something like onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) ??